# Incrementing sequential number on inserts

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a multitenant e-commerce application that manages orders' from different shops. Per each shop, I want to show an order number in a sequential manner.

How can I achieve a sequential increment on the order number per insert without running the risk of duplicating it?

Example

| shopId | orderNumber | items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | hamburger |
| 1 | 2 | hamburger |
| 1 | 3 | hamburger |
| 2 | 1 | hamburger |
| 1 | 2 | hamburger |

New order from shop 1 comes, so orderNumber is increased by 1 (3 + 1 = 4)

| shopId | orderNumber | items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | hamburger |
| 1 | 2 | hamburger |
| 1 | 3 | hamburger |
| 2 | 1 | hamburger |
| 1 | 4 | hamburger |

Comment: Do you want to 1) generate this orderNumber on the fly while querying the database, 2) generate it immediately when inserting the new row, or 3) generate it in a deferred way, maybe seconds or minutes later, after the row was inserted?

Comment: Thanks for the question. Inmediately when inserting!

Comment: Why not use a primary key for this?  They are going to be unique and sequential, and to get the  next one all you would need to do is pass a NULL value to that column, and it will automatically insert the next number after the last one.  If this works its a HUGE time saver for you, because you can let the database figure this out without having to do a single element of math or incremental counting on your end.

Comment: Good question but I think a primary key won't work, at least on MySQL. If an insert fails doesn't the generated sequence number discarded? So there could be a gap in the sequence, which is something I cannot accept given that users would be questioning us "I see order 3, 4 and 6, where is order 5 ?"

Comment: Depends on your insert statement, but usually if the insert fails, it totally fails so it won't use up the next primary key.  PROTIP - make the statement into a stored procedure so you can pass it any parameters you need and thus you can validate the data type coming in to the type you need to insert.  Also .. try MySQL Workbench, if you aren't using it, that would be like doing Excel work in Notepad versus doing it with a GUI and formulas to assists.

Answer (score 1):

For option #2 -- generate the number immediately when inserting the new row -- you'll need some kind of locking mechanism to avoid to concurrent threads to assign the same number to two different orders.

For example, you can create an extra table (this adds redundancy) to store the next number value for each shop:

```sql
create table shop_sequences (
  shop_id int primary key not null,
  next_value int not null
);
```

When inserting a new row, you can:

1. Start a database transaction.
2. Get the next value for the shop and get an exclusive lock for  the row.
3. Increment the next value for the shop.
4. Use the value while inserting the main row.
5. Commit the transaction.

In MySQL this could take the form:

```sql
start transaction;

select next_value from shop_sequences where shop_id = 1234 for update;
-- produces the next_value (e.g. "4") for this shop.

update shop_sequences set next_value = next_value + 1 where shop_id = 1234;

insert into my_orders (shopId, orderNumber, items)
values (1234, 4, 'Hamburger'); -- Use the value "4" retrieved previously

commit;
```